# MySQL 5.6 Command line client create table 1064 error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

Trying to create simple table in sql:

```
CREATE TABLE order (username VARCHAR(20), productid INT, count INT, orderdate VARCHAR(30), price INT);
```

But i got ERROR 1064 (42000) (syntax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

CREATE TABLE _order (username VARCHAR(20), productid INT, count INT, orderdate VARCHAR(30), price INT);

order is a reserved word of mysql. So you cant use it. Refer to this guide. This would help you.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html

Answer (score 0):

`order` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be escaped with backticks. Or use a different name for your table like `orders`

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (...
```